# Ionic 2 Project - Promise issue with authentication

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I've been searching for a solution to this problem I'm having, but haven't found anything that works for my particular case. I am working on an Ionic 2 application and I am working on some authentication stuff for my login screen. The purpose of this file is to add backend functionality to the front end code I wrote (refer to my login.html file on the github link below). I was following the tutorial on this website: 
https://devdactic.com/login-ionic-2/

The problem I am having is that for certain functions, which will be marked in my code, I am getting a "Promise returned from (function) is ignored" which stops the code from functioning entirely. It doesn't come up as a compile error, but instead it is a runtime error that is:

Runtime Error
Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Http! Error at d

I am really not sure what this means, so any insight would be very helpful. If needed, I can provide a picture of the full error.

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {
  loading: Loading;
  registerCredentials = { email: '', password: ''};

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private auth: AuthService, public navParams: NavParams,
  private alertCtrl: AlertController, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {}

  public createAccount() {
    this.navCtrl.push('RegisterPage'); //Promise ignored error
  }

  public login() {
    this.showLoading();
    this.auth.login(this.registerCredentials).subscribe(allowed => {
        if (allowed) {
          this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage'); //Promise ignored error
        } else {
          this.showError("Access Denied");
        }
      },
      error => {
        this.showError(error);
      });
  }

  showLoading() {
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Please wait...',
      dismissOnPageChange: true
    });
    this.loading.present(); //Promise ignored error
  }

  showError(text) {
    this.loading.dismiss(); //Promise ignored error

    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Fail',
      subTitle: text,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present(prompt); //Promise ignored error
  }
}
```

Picture of the error:
[image]

I am just not sure what is causing this problem, and it is causing my code to crash entirely and won't even load my UI. If you need to look at some of the other files, the rest is on my github, this particular file is located in **/src/pages/login**.

The rest of the files:
https://github.com/jparr721/Badmeat/tree/master/BadMeat-Ionic/FirstBuild/src

- IDE: JetBrains WebStorm
- OS: MacOS Sierra
- Ionic Version: 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will fix your problem but try adding the following to your app.module.ts file

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

it may fix your http provider error
you will also have to add it to imports in the same file

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings),
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
```

Comment: only something small but in your auth-service.ts you are missing a space constructor(publichttp: Http) {
    console.log('Hello AuthService Provider');
  }

Comment: Also you are missing your RegisterPage import in Login.ts, Add import { RegisterPage } from '../register/register';

Comment: I hadn't finished the login page yet, do you think that could be causing the issue?

Comment: It will definitely cause issues, no doubt, whether it will fix all your problems im not sure, I'm just narrowing down the problem..I'm on ionic beta so i cant actually run your project myself to debug it so im just going by what i can see

Answer (score 0):

You probably figured it out already but try changing the public to private in your code over here:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
```

try:

```
constructor(private navCtrl: NavController,
```